# System error 86 has occurred.The specified network password is not correct

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to map a network drive in sql server and want to generate a text file as a result of bcp command mentioned below.

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'net use S: \\++.++.++.++\d$ Password/user:administrator/persistent:yes'
EXEC MASTER..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT top 10 macnum, Cus_name,Cus_Email FROM [VBOS_Billing_TSP_CNV_Staging].[dbo].[Cust_file]" queryout S:\BCPResult\Cust_File.txt -T -c'
Exec MASTER.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'net use S: /delete'
```

But I am getting the error :-

```
System error 86 has occurred.
The specified network password is not correct.
```

Please help..

Comment: Well... is the specified network password correct and being sent in the correct format?

Answer (score 0):

Your `NET USE` command is having trouble breaking apart the switches, and is likely seeing everything after `d$` as the password (which is why "The specified network password is not correct."). Add some spaces where appropriate to separate the password from the switches:

```
net use S: \\++.++.++.++\d$ Password /user:administrator /persistent:yes
```

It's also not a bad idea to quote the network path, in case it changes to include spaces or other characters that might throw off the parsing of the command:

```
net use S: "\\++.++.++.++\d$" Password /user:administrator /persistent:yes
```

And make sure you can run the command at a regular command prompt on the computer, as the user executing the query. If you can't, then double check the path and that user's permissions, and that you haven't locked that account due to too many incorrect password attempts.

Comment: Actually it is working fine on local....But giving error on staging..Might be networking issue...I am not able to figure it out..

Comment: Are you using the same account locally as you are for connecting to the staging server? Chances are you are using a local administrator account locally (because you own it and know the password), but that's not the same password for the "Administrator" account on the staging server. You will need to use an account/password that exists on the domain (like a service account) or at least one that exists on the server where the query is executing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have desktop access to the server that's erroring out, you can run Process Monitor to see exactly what's going on.

Download PocMon here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

You'll want to filter for the PID that SQL Server is using, which you can grab from the Services tab of Task Manager.

Go ahead and start a trace by pressing OK, quickly run your TSQL, and then stop the trace with CTRL+E. Hopefully you'll get some ACCESS DENIED results. Double click those and hopefully the info inside of the action properties will help you figure it out.